# How to convert soluble colorless [HgI₄]²⁻ back to insoluble red HgI₂?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, transition-metals, precipitation

When a solution contains $\ce{Hg^2+}$ and $\ce{I-}$, depend on the concentration ratio of $\ce{Hg^2+}$ and $\ce{I-}$, the following reactions can happen:

$$\ce{Hg^2+ + 2 I- ⟶ \underset{insoluble red color solid}{HgI2}}$$

If there is excess $\ce{I-}$, then this red solid will continue to react with excess $\ce{I-}$ to form an colorless soluble complex:

$$\ce{HgI2 + I- ⟶ [HgI3]^-}$$

$$\ce{[HgI3]^- +  I- ⟶ [HgI4]^2-}$$

Is there a way to revert $\ce{[HgI4]^2-}$ back to $\ce{HgI2}$?

Comment: Have you any ideas? There *is* rather trivial solution...

Comment: What I can think of is adding the product [hgi4]2- in the solution so that the equilibrium will be pushed to the left and hgI2 will be formed again.

Comment: No, you should add something else to eliminate the excess, think about proportion of reagents here.

Comment: I can add more Hg2+ in solution to react with the excess I-.

Comment: Indeed, it should work. Technically they react with these complex anions, polymerising until solid particles precipitate AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, to attain mercuric iodide, you need to maintain a balance between the concentration of $\ce{Hg^2+}$ and iodide ion. If there is slight excess of iodide ion, it will form a complex (much like $\ce{KI3}$ from $\ce{KI}$). The complex is popularly known as Nessler's reagent and is prepared pretty much in this way.

Another solution is to decompose the complex to revert back into original products. But I won't recommend this solution. Though, it is expected to give the original reactants, occasionally, decomposition reactions give rise to undesired side products and [may release toxic fumes of mercury, iodine, iodide, potassium oxide($\ce{K2O)}$ etc.](https://www.chemicalbook.com/ChemicalProductProperty_EN_CB2481117.htm) **Do not try to heat the complex.** Instead opt for the 1st solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I will stick with maintaining the balance between the concentration of mercury and iodide ion.